# How do I group by column in Microsoft Report builder?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am making a report at work that shows all sales by state. We sell to the government and civilians. I am trying to make it where there are 4 columns; STATE, TOTAL SALES, CIVILIANS, GOVERNMENT. Only invoice amounts tied to civilians will go under that column for the state, and only invoices for government will go under that column for the state, then the total sales will add both for the state. I have total sales figured out and how to group by state, but I am stumped on grouping by civilian or government. I have spent several days on this.

[Excel report I am trying to make in report builder. Stuff is marked out due to this being work information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEz9l.png)

I have tried expressions, aggragets, tried to group, and it looked like it worked for government but when applied to civilians it diddnt work. This is a simple report I just cant figure out a solution.

Comment: I missed this question as it was not tagged SSRS (reporting-services). If you still need help, show a sample of your data. If the data is structured correctly in your query, this is really easy to do. Edit your question and include the data as text.